# How to render an ASP.NET TreeView programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I am trying to dynamically create a basic ASP.NET TreeView control.  But when I call RenderControl() to get its output, ASP.NET throws null reference exceptions.  What is ASP.NET doing behind the scenes when I declare a TreeView in .ascx/aspx that is NOT happening here?

Broken:

```
    protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        TreeView treeview = new TreeView();
        treeview.SkipLinkText = String.Empty;  //omit this for exception on get_SpacerImageUrl
        treeview.ImageSet = TreeViewImageSet.BulletedList;

        TreeNode node = new TreeNode("Node 1");
        node.ImageUrl = string.Empty;
        node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Subnode 1"));
        node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Subnode 2"));
        treeview.Nodes.Add(node);

        node = new TreeNode("Node 2");
        node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Subnode 1"));
        node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Subnode 2"));
        node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Subnode 3"));
        treeview.Nodes.Add(node);

        treeview.RenderControl(output);
    }
```

Works fine:

```
            <asp:TreeView ID="tvMenu" runat="server">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Node 1">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Section 1"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Section 2"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Section 3"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Node 2">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Section One"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Section Two"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Section Three"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
        </asp:TreeView>
```

The exception:
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.GetImageUrl(Int32 index) +3089
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled) +2329

Comment: In what context are you trying to render this control?

Comment: In a control based on System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.  The HtmlTextWriter is definitely valid.  Rendering simpler controls (like a TextBox) works fine.

Comment: I cannot find a single example of TreeView declared in code-behind anywhere... very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Dynamic TreeView Control in CodeBehind like so:

```
 using (var db = new FORMS())
                {
                    //Get Chapters from selected form
                    var query = from b in db.CHAPTERS
                                select b;

                    //Create treeview hierarchy
                    foreach (var rootItem in query)
                    {
                        TreeNode myNode = new TreeNode(rootItem.titulo, rootItem.id.ToString());

                        var childQuery = from b in db.SECTIONS
                                         select b;
                        //Add childs
                        foreach (var childItem in childQuery)
                        {
                            TreeNode myChildNode = new TreeNode(childItem.titulo, childItem.id.ToString());
                            myNode.ChildNodes.Add(myChildNode);
                        }

                        ChapterTreeView.Nodes.Add(myNode);
                    }
                }
```